# "to wa" Particle? とは?

Tags: translation, particles

This phrase from a song "Deja Vu anata to wa" is translated as "Deja Vu with you"

Does "To wa" translates as "with you" or the entire phrase was adapted? And if so, is that the only use of "to wa" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 「と」 that means "with". The 「は」here is also just the normal topic marker. See [here](http://www.punipunijapan.com/japanese-particle-to/) for some information on the usage of 「と」.